# Joomla 3.3.6 login module redirects when username and password is wrong

Tags: joomla3.0

Joomla 3.3.6 login  module is  redirecting when username and password is wrong.but when i enters right username and password ,it works fine. the problem is that why it is redirecting and not showing message for wrong username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This login module problem caused by configuration file, i am sure you have set wrong path in your logs and temp directory. If above solution not work for you then try this one i am sure this will definitely work for you.
after running this file you`ll find Absoluthe path of your server just copy that path and paste in you log and temp path like

```
   Your Absoluthe Path/logs
     Your Absoluthe Path/temp
```

And your login module work like a charm.